# Algorithm for spatially-based notifications

Tags: algorithm, networking, notifications

I have an app which connects many clients, each having 2d coordinates and a visibility radius assigned. Each client can change its state which should be broadcast to all clients, which have him in their visibility radius. Is there an algorithm which takes a list of changed clients and computes the list of clients which should receive state change notifications? I was thinking of a quadtree-based approach, but I don't know if that's sufficient.